# In flutter How to change FAB (Floating Action Button) custom animation Icon

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am new in flutter and now i am stuck to change FAB animation.Actually i am trying to before i press FAB that time it hadd add Icon and after press FAB it change icon close insted of add icon.
i provide one animation gif file link to more understand if any one know the solution please suggest me to solve this problem.

Here is the link    https://miro.medium.com/max/468/1*qGa6VU4grjqEwAOScRm9BA.gif

In this link provided animation is showing that before press it shows the menu option icon and after press it show close icon but i want add option instead of menu option.

like add_close not a menu_close animationIcon.

I hope you understand my problem and suggest me

Comment: Have you tried coding it yourself? If yes, how much code are you done with?

Comment: yes i tried but it didn't work.thats why i share my problem

Comment: Found this code on GitHub, it's not exactly what you want, but test it and check if the animation is close enough. Can not check it on my own pc :(
https://gist.github.com/agungsb/e85005b0e430781cd1e65829601542d7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code fulfill your requirements.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter FAB Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("FAB"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: AnimatedIconButton(
      
        size: 30,
        onPressed: () {
        },
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        endIcon: Icon(
          Icons.close,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        startIcon: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        startBackgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        endBackgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the namespace which i used:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:animated_icon_button/animated_icon_button.dart';
```

Comment: Thank you so much KK R its work well, now i want add child multiple floating action button when i press fab button can you suggest me if you don't mind?

Comment: I think you have to do more practice in development every time we can't help you in minor things. I will give this suggestion as a elder brother don't get me in wrong way okay.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for all your requirements such as animation,multiple fab buttons with on pressed and also support images as a fab icon.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter FAB Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: UniWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class UniWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UniWidgetState createState() => _UniWidgetState();
}

class _UniWidgetState extends State<UniWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var childButtons = List<UnicornButton>();

    childButtons.add(UnicornButton(
        hasLabel: false,
        currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          mini: false,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/arrow.png'),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            print('scanbar');
          },
        )));

    childButtons.add(UnicornButton(
        hasLabel: false,
        currentButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          mini: false,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/contact.png'),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            print('Contact');
          },
        )));

    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: UnicornDialer(
            parentButtonBackground: Colors.blue,
            orientation: UnicornOrientation.VERTICAL,
            childPadding: 10.0,
            parentButton: Icon(Icons.add),
            childButtons: childButtons),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Fab demo"),
        ),
        body: Center());
  }
}
```

here is the namespaces

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:unicorndial/unicorndial.dart';
```

I hope it will fulfill your all type of requirements and work well in your project.

Comment: once again Thank you KK R .